# Spring Async breaks JPA - detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

Using H2 and JPA my REST app worked well before Ansyc, but after implementation breaks the JPA persistence model.

Here is the case:

My repository has a method `JpaRepository.save()` but when called from a separate thread, it throws `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` error.

My **Controller** calls the **Service** which calls the **Repository** to insert a new object, and I get  the following error:

`InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: TransactionalEntity; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: TransactionalEntity]`

CONTROLLER:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("depositIntentService")
private TransactionIntentService depositIntentService;

@PostMapping("/services/transactions/deposit")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<TransactionIntent>> deposit(@Valid @RequestBody TransactionClientRequest request) {

    CompletableFuture<TransactionIntent> depositIntentFuture = 
        transactionIntentFactory.createDepositIntent(
                request.entity.id,
                Money.of(CurrencyUnit.of(request.money.currency), request.money.amount));   

    return depositIntentFuture.thenApply(intent -> {
        TransactionIntent publishedIntent = depositIntentService.attemptPublish(intent);    //<-- causes error
        ResponseEntity.ok(publishedIntent)
    });
}
```

SERVICE:

```
@Component
@Repository
public abstract class TransactionIntentServiceImpl implements TransactionIntentService{

    @Autowired
    private TransactionIntentRepository transactionIntentRepo;

    @Transactional
    public TransactionIntent attemptPublish(TransactionIntent intent){
        transactionIntentRepo.save(intent);     //<-- Throws error: ...detached entity passed to persist

    }
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionIntentRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionIntent, Long>{
}
```

Any ideas how to support JPA persistance in an Async environment?
Thanks!

**Update1**

FACTORY

```
@Component
public class TransactionIntentFactory {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<TransactionIntent> createDepositIntent(long beneficiaryId, Money money) {

        CompletableFuture<User> bank = userService.findByUsername("bankItself@bank.com");
        CompletableFuture<User> user = userService.find(beneficiaryId);

        CompletableFuture<Void> allUserFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(bank, user);

        return allUserFutures.thenApply(it -> {
            User userSource = bank.join();
            User userBeneficiary = user.join();

            TransactionIntent intent = new TransactionIntentBuilder()
                .status(new TransactionIntentStatus(TRANSFER_STATUS.CREATED, "Deposit"))
                .beneficiary(userBeneficiary)
                .source(userSource)
                .amount(money)
                .build();

            return intent;

        });
    }

}
```

ENTITY

```
@Entity
public class TransactionIntent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;

    public final Money amount;
    public final Date createdAt;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public final TransactionIntentStatus status;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public final TransactionalEntity beneficiary;   //to

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public final TransactionalEntity source;            //from

    TransactionIntent(){
        this.amount= null;
        this.createdAt = null;
        this.status = null;
        this.beneficiary = null;
        this.source = null;
    }

    public TransactionIntent(TransactionIntentBuilder builder) {
        this.amount = builder.amount;
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.status = builder.status;
        this.beneficiary = builder.beneficiary;
        this.source = builder.source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the id of the TransactionIntent in the TransactionIntentFactory?  If so, this could be the cause of this error.  Having the code for the createDepositIntent factory method would be helpful.  Providing the annotations/source for the TransactionIntent entity would be useful as well.

Comment: @C.Springer The intent it is not set by me but is annotated w/ 'Id' and 'GeneratedValue' and so set by the db. Please see updates for the Factory and Entity code. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the TransactionalEntity (User) is attached on another thread than the TransactionIntent. When I remove the 'cascade=CascadeType.ALL' it doesn't throw the error. But doing so means I that there is a separate "persistence" on each thread. How can I operate on a single instance of the jpa persistance?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a project using Spring Integration once upon a time.  My solution as I remember it was to store just the id of the object being referenced in the database and defer actual retrieval to the code/thread actually doing the persistence.  In your case, there would need to be some sort of pre-persist operation (presumably in attemptPublish) that would tell the TransactionIntent object to load the appropriate objects into the current HibernateSession and then persist the object.

Comment: I wanted to add some food for thought here and suggest that you reconsider your heavy use of CompletableFuture altogether.  For example, your service returns a CompletableFuture when retrieving User objects but then calls join(), thus being executed serially.  In this case the future is added complexity.  Perhaps another, more Hibernate-friendly, solution would involve the creation of some Serializable, throw-away value object that represents the pending transaction that could be passed across threads.  The code in the future would then perform all persistence/lookup operations.